# How to make selenium identify correct key when there are several starting with same letter

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm webscraping an .asp page with Selenium (in R) and to extract what i want i need to fill a form. The first Element of my form allows for several options like: "SIN", "S","SE/CO","N" and "NE".

At first I've named the Keys (at sendKeysToElement) as those exact names, but then i've realised selenium was selecting SE/CO when it was supposed to select S. The same happened to NE and N - Selenium simply selects the first of the options that appear at the form.

So I thought that maybe if I've changed the name keys to the name appearing at the source code i'd be fine. So i did that (so instead of "S" it would be "SUL", instead of "NE" it would be "NORDESTE" and so forth), but the problem continued. I don't know how to change that.

Here's my code:

```
library(RSelenium)

regioes=c("SIN" ,"SUL", "NORTE", "NORDESTE" ,"SE/CO")

checkForServer()
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
mybrowser$open()

for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in 2000:2016){
    mybrowser$navigate("http://www.ons.org.br/historico/carga_propria_de_energia.aspx")

    regiao <-mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#passo1 select")
    regiao$sendKeysToElement(list(regioes[i]))

    medida<-mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#passo2b select")
    medida$sendKeysToElement(list("MWmed"))

    periodicidade<-mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#passo3b select")
    periodicidade$sendKeysToElement(list("mensal"))

    ano<-mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#passo4b select")
    ano$sendKeysToElement(list(as.character(j)))

    gerar <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#btn_p5")
    gerar$clickElement()

    planilha<-mybrowser$findElement(using='link text',"Fazer download da planilha")
    planilha$clickElement()
}}
```

I know that if i ask selenium to asign another key to element, it will look for the second option (now that it already tried the first one)... So it would suffice to include the line

```
if(i==2|i==3){regiao$sendKeysToElement(list(regioes[i]))}
```

after

```
regiao$sendKeysToElement(list(regioes[i]))
```

but that's a poor solution and given I'm in a loop, that won't do. I was hoping for a more elegant solution (or just understand why it's not working the way it was suppose to)

Someone has any suggestions?

Comment: The website is not available anymore. Could you provide an updated weblink?